# Using qgis python to create a PDF output with print composer to only show the attribute table

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, print-composer, pdf

I'm attempting to show the information of a given vector layer that I have by creating a PDF file that shows the attribute table of that same vector layer.

The problem I have is that currently I get an output, but only up to the sixth feature of the attribute table. However I want to display the **entire** attribute table no matter how many features there are.

- I have tried using different layers, same result occurs
- I have looked online for a solution extensively. The code that I am using is based of the sources that I have found by looking online.
- I am **not** looking to include any other information other than the attribute table as of now
- It is not the number of features or attributes. I've tested a layer with 10 features which should easily fit on the page but no features past the sixth feature are shown.

I believe that something with my code needs to be altered, however no matter how I tinker with it, I can't seem to get more than 6 rows to appear on the PDF file. I'm not entirely sure what needs to be changed as it's always 6, and only 6 rows.

## Code

```
from qgis.gui import *

huff_model = iface.activeLayer()

mapRenderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
c = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
c.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
x, y = 0, 0
w, h = c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight()
composerMap = QgsComposerMap(c, x, y, w, h)

table = QgsComposerAttributeTable(c)
table.setComposerMap(composerMap)
table.setVectorLayer(huff_model)
c.addItem(table)

printer = QPrinter()
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName("C:/Users/Oski/Py_internship/Huff_Model_Oski/Outputs/out.pdf")
printer.setPaperSize(QSizeF(c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight()), QPrinter.Millimeter)
printer.setFullPage(True)

pdfPainter = QPainter(printer)
paperRectMM = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Millimeter)
paperRectPixel = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.DevicePixel)
c.render(pdfPainter, paperRectPixel, paperRectMM)
pdfPainter.end()
```

This code can be run straight from the python console (I used it like this for testing), provided that there is a valid vector layer with an attribute table.

## PDF Output

[image]

My apologizes for the poor image, it was difficult to capture the entire page with decent resolution. Nevertheless, it's evident what my output looks like; there are only 6 rows shown despite the fact that the vector layer has over 1000 features. I am aware that not all the attributes fit on the page, I'm only concerned with why the remaining features do not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before you add the table to the composer try adding:

```
table.setMaximumNumberOfFeatures(huff_model.featureCount())
```